# Cannot Serialize using GSON for JSON Array inside JSON Array

Tags: java, gson

I need some help to deserialize this JSON Response to array which I can use further

Json Array response that I am getting  has two entities tradingHours and shutDownHours

Creating a Json reader for the Json Response and , looping in the reader until I get to shutDown node and then try to get the details using ShutdownHours class

**"I cannot create a gson object from JSON response using the Trading Hours class , what am I missing here**

JSON RESPONSE

```
{
    "licenceNumber": "123319",
    "tradingHours": [
        {
            "effectiveStartDate": "1947-12-01T00:00:00",
            "effectiveEndDate": "2008-06-30T00:00:00",
            "details": [
                {
                    "day": "Monday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "12:00 midnight"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "12:00 midnight"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Wednesday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "12:00 midnight"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Thursday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "12:00 midnight"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "12:00 midnight"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Saturday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "12:00 midnight"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Sunday",
                    "startTime": "10:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "11:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Good Friday",
                    "startTime": "10:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Christmas Day",
                    "startTime": "10:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "December 31st",
                    "startTime": "10:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 PM"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "effectiveStartDate": "2008-07-01T00:00:00",
            "effectiveEndDate": null,
            "details": [
                {
                    "day": "Monday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Wednesday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Thursday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Saturday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Sunday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Good Friday",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "December 24th",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Christmas Day",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "December 31st",
                    "startTime": "5:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "5:00 AM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "shutdownHours": [
        {
            "effectiveStartDate": "2003-02-27T00:00:00",
            "isPrimary": "Y",
            "details": [
                {
                    "day": "Monday",
                    "startTime": "2:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "8:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "startTime": "2:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "8:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Wednesday",
                    "startTime": "2:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "8:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Thursday",
                    "startTime": "2:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "8:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "startTime": "2:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "8:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Saturday",
                    "startTime": "2:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "8:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Sunday",
                    "startTime": "2:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "8:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "PublicHoliday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "effectiveStartDate": "1947-12-01T00:00:00",
            "isPrimary": null,
            "details": [
                {
                    "day": "Monday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Wednesday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Thursday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Saturday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "Sunday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "day": "PublicHoliday",
                    "startTime": "4:00 AM",
                    "endTime": "10:00 AM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Java CODE

```
public static TradingHours readTradingHours(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
      ShutdownHours tradingHours = null;
      reader.beginObject();
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      while (reader.hasNext()) {

         String name = reader.nextName();
         if (name.equals("tradingHours")) {
            reader.beginArray();
            tradingHours = gson.fromJson(reader, ShutdownHours.class);
         }
         else {
            reader.skipValue();

         }
      }

      return tradingHours;
   }
```

> ```
> TRADING HOURS CLASS , This class is used to create an object and is being used to create gson
> ```

```
    package com.tattsgroup.site.entity.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class TradingHours implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("effectiveStartDate")
    private String effectiveStartDate;

    @SerializedName("effectiveEndDate")
    private String getEffectiveEndDate;

    @SerializedName("details")
    private List<TradingHourDetails> tradingHoursDetails;

    public TradingHours() {
    }

    public TradingHours(String effectiveStartDate, String getEffectiveEndDate, List<TradingHourDetails> tradingHoursDetails) {

        this.effectiveStartDate = effectiveStartDate;
        this.getEffectiveEndDate = getEffectiveEndDate;
        this.tradingHoursDetails = tradingHoursDetails;
    }

    public String getEffectiveStartDate() {
        return effectiveStartDate;
    }

    public void setEffectiveStartDate(String effectiveStartDate) {
        this.effectiveStartDate = effectiveStartDate;
    }

    public String getGetEffectiveEndDate() {
        return getEffectiveEndDate;
    }

    public void setGetEffectiveEndDate(String getEffectiveEndDate) {
        this.getEffectiveEndDate = getEffectiveEndDate;
    }

    public List<TradingHourDetails> getTradingHoursDetails() {
        return tradingHoursDetails;
    }

    public void setTradingHoursDetails(List<TradingHourDetails> tradingHoursDetails) {
        this.tradingHoursDetails = tradingHoursDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using jackson or moxy

Comment: What exactly do you want to do...I'm unable to understand the problem here...This json can converted to a Class Structure easily...what more do you want?

Comment: @utkarsh31 "I cannot create a gson object from JSON response using the Trading Hours class , what am I missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you do not have to use `JsonReader` and just want to deserialize `TradingHours` from the Json you provided. I guess it is possible with `JsonReader` but there is an easier way to do it.

Create a class that describes the response - and which wraps everything in the response - as it is, simply:

```
@Getter
public class HoursResponse {
    private Long licenceNumber; // you can remove licenseNumber if not needed
    private TradingHours[] tradingHours;
    // add also this if needed later
    // private ShutdownHours shutdownHours;
}
```

Deserialize that class:

```
HoursResponse hr = gson.fromJson(json, HoursResponse.class);
```

and access `TradingHours` by:

```
TradingHours[] tradingHours = hr.getTradingHours();
```

Also I suggest you to change the class name `TradingHours` to `TradingHour` and `TradingHourDetails` to `TradingHourDetail`. Plural is usually used in names referring to lists or so. For example, following makes more sense:

```
TradingHour[] tradingHours = hr.getTradingHours();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pirho , I had got the solution , but it was too complex and less readable . This solution works for me . I am new to Java serialization and now have a good understanding of it